# Docker - SFTP installation

Tags: docker, sftp

I am trying for installing SFTP in the Docker container.

I have the following in my Dockerfile. Able to install ntp this way, but failing for sftp. May I know the command?

```
RUN yum install -y ntp \
    && yum install -y sftp
```

Comment: Both of those things would be unusual to run in Docker containers, and especially together in a single container.  But the actual error message, and the complete Dockerfile that included the base image, would be essential to help at all.

Comment: As per the official close reasons: _Question is seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem._

Comment: "failing for sftp" isn't an adequate description of the failure. You have more logging available that indicates the nature of the failure. You should provide it. You should also provide information about the docker image that you are using, and about this `sftp` package that you are trying to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add more information such as:

- Linux version (if your container is a Redhat, CentOS, version...)
- Command you've executed to build / run.
- Error message.

Anyway, you can try with this while we wait for your additional info:

```
RUN yum install -y ntp \
    && yum install -y vsftpd
```